# How to download all images from a gallery

Tags: images, wget

I'm searching for a way to download all images (not the thumbnails) of this gallery

> http://kinki.de/#/?gallery=list&gid=4804 .

As I can see, the images are all located at

> http://kinki.de/files/galleries/4804/

I tried it with some googled `wget` commands but I always get `403 Forbidden` Error or it just have been a robots.txt downloaded. Is there a chance to handle my concern with wget or httrack?

`wget` commands I already tried:

```
wget -nd -r -l 1 -A jpg http://kinki.de/files/galleries/4804/
wget -nd -H -p -A jpg -e robots=off http://kinki.de/files/galleries/4804/
wget -U Firefox -e robots=off http://kinki.de/files/galleries/4804/
wget -m -np http://kinki.de/files/galleries/4804/
wget -H -r --level=1 -k -p http://kinki.de/files/galleries/4804/
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" http://kinki.de/files/galleries/4804/
```

Comment: What commands did you already try?

Comment: I edited my question.